Proving that Metric on the set of compact subsets of a metric space inherited from the metric space (Hausdorff metric) satisfies triangle inequality
On a metric space $(M,d)$ and $A \in K(M)$, the set of compact subsets of $M$, we define the function $h: M \times K(M) -> \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, as $h(a,B) = \text{min} \{d(a,b): b \in B\}$, and from this we define a function $\tilde{d}: K(M) \times K(M) \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined as
$$ \tilde{d} (A,B) = \text{max} ( \text{max }    \{ h(a,B)| a\in A \}, \text{max }\{ h(A,b) | b \in B\})$$
We must prove that $\tilde{d}$ is a metric. It is easy to prove reflexivity and symmetry condition of the metric, but the triangle inequality is quite tricky. We must prove that:
$$\tilde{d}(A,B) +\tilde{d}(B,C) \geq \tilde{d}(A,C)$$
Now, the difficulty in proving this is that, suppose we start with the left side, then we would have to denest the maxs and get it somehow to a point where we have addition of something with involving the metric function itself, as only for it do we actually know the triangle inequality is true.
I think perhaps the following lemma may help us in denesting:

If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are metrics on a set $M$, then so is $\text{max} (d_1,d_2)$

It maybe worth to note that when one does the part of the proof where they prove the triangle inequality for  $\text{max} (d_1,d_2)$,the proof only depends on the triangle inequality being true for $d_1$ and $d_2$.
So, I suppose if I can prove that $\phi: K(M) \times K(M) \to \mathbb{R}$, defined as $\phi(A,B) =  \text{max }    \{ h(a,B)| a\in A \}$ satisfies simply the triangle inequality then I am immediately done with the question.
I think for denesting the maximum for proof of the triangle inequality for $\phi$, we must use the following identity

$$\text{max } (a,b) +\text{max } (c,d) = \text{max } (a+c,a+d,b+c,b+d)$$

However, actually doing it in practice I get something which is best described as a calculation hell.
Is there an easier way to go about this?

Related questions this and linked. However, none of them take the approach that I do.

You’re overcomplicating this. For any $a \in A$, $\epsilon > 0$, by definition of $\tilde{d}$, there exists $b \in B$ s.t. $d(a, b) \leq \tilde{d}(A, B) + \epsilon$. Similarly, there exists $c \in C$ s.t. $d(b, c) \leq \tilde{d}(B, C) + \epsilon$, so,
$$h(a, C) \leq d(a, c) \leq d(a, b) + d(b, c) \leq \tilde{d}(A, B) + \tilde{d}(B, C) + 2\epsilon$$
Letting $\epsilon$ goes to $0$ shows $h(a, C) \leq \tilde{d}(A, B) + \tilde{d}(B, C)$ for any $a \in A$. Similarly, $h(c, A) \leq \tilde{d}(A, B) + \tilde{d}(B, C)$ for any $c \in C$. Taking supremum then shows $\tilde{d}(A, C) \leq \tilde{d}(A, B) + \tilde{d}(B, C)$.
(Since the sets are compact, I could have used $\epsilon = 0$ - but the above implies restricting to compact sets is not necessary. The triangle inequality is always satisfied regardless of whether $A$, $B$, and $C$ are compact or not. Also, this is known as the Hausdorff distance.)

I miswrote. I meant Finding a $b$ for a given epsilon. It reminds me of the procedure that we do when we do limtis. That's why I said I felt that it feels topological. I don't quite understand this answer. Perhaps a picture may help? I'll try rereading a few times tho

@Babu If I’m trying to prove triangle inequality for $\tilde{d}$, and the only thing I know satisfies the triangle inequality is the original metric $d$, then certainly I’d like to apply that. So I need actual points $a \in A$, then $b \in B$, then $c \in C$ to apply the triangle inequality for $d$. And if I want to minimize the distance between $a$ and $c$, I would certainly want to find a $b \in B$ which is as close as possible to $a$, then a $c \in C$ which is as close as possible to $b$. And that is exactly how the proof goes. It’s all quite natural.

I don’t really have a way to draw a picture at the moment. Just draw a picture yourself and follow along the proof procedure in finding $b$ and $c$. It’s really not complicated.

Could you explain why my line of thinking is inefficient or incorrect? Do you think it'd be impossible to prove the required if I somehow tried to follow throw with my approach=?

@Babu The $\phi$ you defined does satisfy the triangle inequality - by effectively the same proof as in my answer. But if you’ve already done that you might as well just write down the full proof as in my answer. As for the equation for the sum of two maxima, I’m honestly not sure what you’re trying to do with it.

If you bash out the proof for  triangle inequality of $\text{max } (d_1,d_2)$ one of the steps I used was to used that mentioned of maximum followed by the fact that if I have a maximum of set things, that is always greater or equal than maximum of subset of those things.
I thought, a similar concept in some other way could be applied this yet larger proof.

@Babu That only reduces things to $h$. But $h$ is defined using minimum instead of maximum, and everything after that is just a mess. Not saying it necessarily couldn’t be done, but I can’t really see how exactly you can make it work. And even if it does it’s just going to be unnecessarily complicated anyway.
